# Waiting to upgrade 14.04.4 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, dell

I have waited for the automatic upgrade message from the Software Updater,
 but no upgrade message.  Some  information from the terminal program follows:

```
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$ date
Fri Jul 22 11:10:12 EDT 2016
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$ date
Fri Jul 22 11:11:04 EDT 2016
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$ ^C
william@william-Inspiron-3537:~$
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You can run `do-release-upgrade -d` or wait a little to get it working without `-d`.

Comment: OMG Ubuntu says that the automatic upgrade message is working..

Comment: Maybe you did not get the update yet from a local mirror.

Comment: 'While Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS has been released, automatic upgrades from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will not begin until "early next week" according to the Ubuntu Release Team.' https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4tzgou/ubuntu_16041_lts_released_1404_users_see_upgrade/d5lp6s4

Comment: OMG Ubuntu is, to put it bluntly, incorrect.

Comment: Is It really a bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1529307